# Xcode 6 access UIApplication from UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

I have a simple application that stores user information using CoreData. I'm very new to Xcode, so forgive my ignorance, but it seems I am not including the right modules because Xcode is not autocompleting classes like `UIApplication`, `NSManagedObjectContext`, and `NSEntityDescription` (and their functions).

Also I am getting some errors (shown in the screenshot).

Do I need to import another module so they are recognized?

[image]

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class OutlineViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var textFieldTitle: UITextField = nil
    @IBOutlet weak var textFieldTag: UITextField = nil

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func saveTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
        let appDel: AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate

        let context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext
        let en: NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Outline", inManagedObjectContext: context)
        // I get the error on the above line that "Consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ';'" and it suggests that I place a semicolon after entityForName

        var newItem = Model(entity: en, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: context)

        newItem.title = textFieldTitle.text
        newItem.Tag = textFieldTag.text

        context.save(nil)

        println(newItem)

        self.navigationController.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }    
}
```

From what I've read in the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSEntityDescription_Class/index.html), `NSEntityDescription` is part of `CoreData`. Why is it not being recognized?

Answer (score 0):

You are giving statement where type declaration is required. You forgot the assignment:

```
let en: NSEntityDescription? = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Outline", inManagedObjectContext: context)
```

To fix all other issues check out:

```
class OutlineViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var textFieldTitle: UITextField? = nil
    @IBOutlet weak var textFieldTag: UITextField? = nil

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func saveTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
        let appDel: AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate

        let context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext
        let en: NSEntityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Outline", inManagedObjectContext: context)!
        // I get the error on the above line that "Consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ';'" and it suggests that I place a semicolon after entityForName

        var newItem = Model(entity: en, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: context)

        newItem.title = textFieldTitle.text
        newItem.Tag = textFieldTag.text

        context.save(nil)

        println(newItem)

        self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }    
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment, but that seemed to throw some other interesting errors http://imgur.com/4ldT2MG

Comment: Seems that you are not unwrapping or optional chaining optional variables. Check out the updated answer.